# Function dentro de un if else

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, php7

poseo la siguiente function en PHP

```
      function verificar_status(){
                global $db, $username, $usua, $ci_nro_cuenta, $monto, $nro_transf, $banco_emisor, $banco_destino, $fecha_transf, $status_pedido, $fecha_pedido, $status_pago, $fecha_aprobacion;

                $query = "SELECT * FROM pedidos  WHERE usuario = '$usua' AND status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                $rows =  mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($rows > 0){

            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"" >
                        <h3>
                LO SENTIMOS, USTED POSEE UN PEDIDO EN ESPERA        
                        </h3>
                    </div>';


        } else {

    verificar_pago_mes();

      echo ' <form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "pedidos.php">
         AQUI VA UN FORMULARIO
        </form>';
            } 

        }

//y por otra parte tengo la function 

function verificar_pago_mes() { 
    global $db, $username, $usua, $mes_de_pago_actual;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pagos WHERE user = '$usua' AND mes_de_pago = '$mes_de_pago_actual'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $rows =  mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($rows > 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"" >
        <h3>'
.$mes_de_pago_actual .' Pagado      
        </h3>
    </div>';  


    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"" >
        <h3>
Lo sentimos usted no ha efectuado el pago correspondiente a ' .$mes_de_pago_actual .'       
        </h3>
    </div>';
    exit;
    }

}
```

Mi intencion es que luego de que se analice `verificar_pago_mes()` se pueda ejecutar dentro de `verificar_status()` pero resulta que no muestra nada en el MODAL donde esta saliendo `verificar_status()` si comento la ultima linea `exit;` si muestra el alert pero tambien muestra el formulario.

Intente haciendo un `if (verificar_pago_mes()=true)` pero logicamente me indica error..!

Agradezco alguna idea que me permita implementar la function de manera correcta.

Comment: Esas funciones son parte de una clase? si es así probaste colocando $this->verificar_pago_mes()?

Comment: Saludos @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder, usando tu sugerencia tiene el mismo comportamiento

Comment: Vamos a ver por partes, tienes configurado el php para que te muestre todos los errores? quizás esta saltando un error y no lo puedes ver

Comment: Si pero no es un error como tal, es que el exit de la function como que paraliza la ejecucion de toda la function, resolvi de manera temporal efectuando 2 consultas dentro del if uno antes del if y uno despues del else y me ha de funcionar asi, pero si a futuro quisiera hacer otro modulo no quisiera copiar y repetir todo el codigo

Comment: El exit detiene todo, lo que deberías de hacer es un return en la función verificar_pago_mes y no un exit, es decir almacenar el valor devuelto por la función verificar_pago_mes en una variable dentro de la función verificar_status. En verificar_pago_mes  debería de retornar ya sea el contenido del if o el else a través de un return y verificar_status lo recibirá en una variable quedando algo como $pago = verificar_pago_mes() y esa variable $pago la usas como te de la gana dentro o fuera del formulario que viene después o evaluar el valor retornado para mostrar o no el formulario.